# How to scrape a Facebook page of which I am not an administrator

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping

As part of an academic project I need to scrape the data from a Facebook page of which **I am not an admin**, I did some research and I found that this is possible via Facebook Developper but that in the case where I am the admin of the page. If you have any suggestions that will help me in my case, I will be grateful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**use :User Profile API:**

### Available Profile Fields

### developers.facebook.com

> By default, your apps may retrieve the id, name, first_name,
> last_name, and profile_pic fields for user's that have made this
> information public and have opted-in to your Page.

On This Page
User Profile API

The User Profile API allows you to use a Page-scoped ID (PSID) to retrieve user profile information that can be used to personalize the experience of people interacting with your Messenger.
Contents

```
Availability
    User Opt-in
    Profile Unavailable
Available Profile Fields
Retrieving a Person's Profile
Last Ad Referral
Error Codes
```

Availability

Though you may have a PSID, you may not have permission or be able to retrieve a person's profile information. For example Instant Game Pages are not allowed to use this API.
User Opt-in

The following events will authorize your Messenger bot to access a person's profile information:

```
The person starts the conversation via a welcome screen and tapped the "Get Started" button.
The person starts the conversation by clicking a "Send to Messenger" button.
The person starts the conversation by sending a message.
The person starts the conversation by accepting a Page's message request.
Your Messenger bot uses the askPermission() function of the Messenger Extensions SDK in the webview to ask for the user_profile permission.
```

Some entry points allow you or people to initiate a conversation without giving your bot authorization to the person's public profile. In those cases, your Messenger bot will be granted permission to access user profile after the user replied to the initial message. Notable situations where a person may initiate a conversation with your Messenger bot, but not authorize profile permission include the following:

```
Conversations started via the Checkbox Plugin and the user did has not responded on Messenger.
Interactions with Ads that Click to Messenger before the user replies on Messenger
```

Profile Unavailable

Currently, the User Profile API does not support retrieving profile information for Messenger accounts that were created using a phone number instead of a Facebook account.

In this case, the API will return error code 2018218 with the message 'No profile available for this user.'
Available Profile Fields

By default, your apps may retrieve the id, name, first_name, last_name, and profile_pic fields for user's that have made this information public and have opted-in to your Page.

Apps can query via the API, which fields are available for a given Page. See Feature Review API

The following profile fields can be requested:
Field Name  Description     Feature Access

id

The user's PSID

Granted by default

name

The user's first and last name

Granted by default

first_name

First name

Granted by default

last_name

Last name

Granted by default

profile_pic

URL to the Profile picture. The URL will expire.

Granted by default

locale

Locale of the user on Facebook. For supported locale codes, see Supported Locales.

This Page level feature needs approval by Facebook

timezone

Timezone, number relative to GMT

This Page level feature needs approval by Facebook

gender

Gender

This Page level feature needs approval by Facebook
Requesting feature access to user fields for the Page

> Go to Page Settings > Advanced Messaging
> Under 'Info About People' select the field and click the 'Request' button.

ref:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if I understood correctly this API works to extract information from a facebook profil. Indeed I need an API that allows me to extract information from a facebook page (number of likes in a post, comments...)

Comment: Excuse Watch this Example:  https://github.com/lineshjose/Facebook-Page-Likes-count/blob/master/facebook-likes-count.php